# Reading Objects From A File to An Input Stream

Tags: java, objectinputstream, treemaps

I am presently working on a simple `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`, I have read both the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and the Java [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html) and am familiar with the basics; however, in attempting to compile my program, I am encountering an error that may be related to my misunderstanding of the **combination of `Map`s and Object input/output**, specifically the input portion.

I have a .dat file, from which I am trying to read a list of objects that get mapped into a `TreeMap`:

```
public class Product implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int code;
    private String name;
    private int quatity;

    // Setters and Getters

}
```

Above, is the code fragment for the `Product` object, itself - implementing `Serializable`. I include the fragment in case the problem lies, there.

For this question, assume the .dat is not empty and contains properly formatted data.

Here is my `ObjectInputStream` code:

```
try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            products = (Map<Integer, Product>) inputStream.readObject();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfException  {      
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + cnfException.getMessage());
        }
        catch (EOFException eofException) {
            System.err.println("EOFException: " + eofException.getMessage());
        }   
}
```

When attempting to run this code, I get the following error (a Cast error):

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Here is how I am writing `Product` objects to the .dat file:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new    FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
        outputStream.writeObject(products.get(i));
    }
}
```

Having isolated the error, I know the error occurs when I hit the `products =` portion. I am unsure if this is a compound issue or if this is one of two issues:

1. I am not properly grabbing the data from the file in order to populate the `TreeMap`
2. I am misunderstanding the implementation of `ObjectInputStream`

Comment: How did the .dat file get created? It appears that a Product object was written, not a Map.

Comment: Let me add a description of that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you originally just wrote the `Product` objects to an `ObjectOutputStream`, rather than a `Map<Integer, Product>`. If that's the case, you need something like:

```
Map<Integer, Product> products = new TreeMap<>();
try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    while (true) {
        Product product = (Product) input.readObject();
        products.put(product.getCode(), product); // Or whatever
    }
} catch (EOFException e) {
    // Just finish? Kinda nasty...
}
```

Of course, that will throw an exception when it reaches the end of the stream - you might want to think about how you're going to detect that cleanly rather than just handling the exception.